# error building project with phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova

Hi every one i am stuck in a place where i want to build my project with phonegap build ,But i am Getting a erro message .
 

" Error - One of your icons or splashscreens is not a valid PNG. Please view the build logs to see which file is causing this error ." 

i have tried everything to solve this issue by changing my icon.png file and its resolution  as well as changed all the icons from res/icon/android directory but nothing is working for me .Please Suggest me Any solution .

Answer (score 0):

Oh! My mistake i was using PNG Image Instead of PNG Icon .

Issue Resolved by changing Png Icon .